# composer update gives error

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, composer-php

Whenever I run composer update it gives me following:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Generating autoload files
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file



  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\OutOfBoundsException]  
  The index "4" is not in the range [0, 3].                               



Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.  



Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/api.agorafy.com/trunk/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:190
 Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::executeCommand() at /var/www/api.agorafy.com/trunk/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:62
 Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:206
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->executeEventPhpScript() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:174
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:120
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchCommandEvent() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:336
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:136
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:252
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:146
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:43
 require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:25


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

I am not able to resolve it I have tried following things:

1. Clear Cache before running composer update.
2. Delete bin and vendor folder then run composer update.
3. system restart.
4. uninstall APC (not sure about this but uninstalled apc)
   Please help on this issue.

My Composer.json is this:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php":                                      ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony":                          "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm":                             "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle":                 "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions":                          "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle":                   "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle":               "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle":                   "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle":               "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle":            "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle":                  "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler":     "2.1.*@dev",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle":                      "1.5.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle":             "1.4.*@dev",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle":                    "2.5.*@dev",
        "willdurand/hateoas-bundle":                "1.0.*@dev",
        "hautelook/templated-uri-bundle":           "1.0.*@dev",
        "willdurand/rest-extra-bundle":             "1.0.*@dev",
        "escapestudios/wsse-authentication-bundle": "2.3.x-dev",
        "knplabs/gaufrette":                        "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle":             "dev-master",
        "amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php":        "dev-master",
        "cybernox/amazon-webservices-bundle":       "dev-master",
        "escapestudios/wsse-authentication-bundle": "2.3.x-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle":        "2.2.*",
        "symfony/filesystem":                       "2.5.*@dev",
        "snc/redis-bundle":                         "1.1.x-dev",
        "predis/predis":                            "0.8.x-dev",
        "hwi/oauth-bundle":                         "0.4.*@dev"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "discard-changes": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

### **EDIT**

### **services.yml**

```
parameters:
    application_p_api.userprovider.class: Application\PApiBundle\Provider\UserProvider
    application_p_api.amazon_s3.class: AmazonS3
    application_p_api.file_uploader.class: Application\PApiBundle\Services\FileUploader
    application_p_api.tsession.class: Application\PApiBundle\Services\TSSession

services:
    service.s3nfs:
        class: Application\PApiBundle\Services\s3nfs
        arguments: [@service_container]

    application_p_api.amazon_s3:
        class: %application_p_api.amazon_s3.class%
        arguments: 
            - { key: %aws_key%, secret: %aws_secret% }
    amazon_api_service: "@application_p_api.amazon_s3" #alias to application_p_api.amazon_s3 service

    application_p_api.file_uploader:
        class: %application_p_api.file_uploader.class%
        arguments: [@file_uploader_filesystem, @service_container]

    application_p_api.mailer:
        class: Application\PApiBundle\Services\MailsSender
        arguments: ['@service_container', '@mailer', '@twig']
        public: true
    mails_sender: "@application_p_api.mailer"   #alias to application_p_api.mailer service

    application_p_api.tsession:
        class: Application\PApiBundle\Services\TSSession
        arguments: [@service_container]

    #Form Validator Services
    p_api_contact_email_validator:
        class: Application\PApiBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContactEmailValidator
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.read_only_entity_manager]
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: contact_email_validator }

    p_api_not_user_email_validator:
        class: Application\PApiBundle\Validator\Constraints\NotUserEmailValidator
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.read_only_entity_manager]
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: not_user_email_validator }

    p_api_not_pending_user_email_validator:
        class: Application\PApiBundle\Validator\Constraints\NotPendingUserEmailValidator
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.read_only_entity_manager]
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: not_pending_user_email_validator }

    p_api_password_requirements_validator:
        class: Application\PApiBundle\Validator\Constraints\PasswordStrengthValidator
        arguments: ~
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: password_requirements_validator }
```

Rest of the Code is Here: 
https://github.com/jbpashu/composer-error-analysis-code

Please have a look if needed.

Comment: Does it still happen if you delete the `cache/*` directories by hand?

Comment: yes, I have already tried cache:clear and deleting folders manually.

Comment: can you post the `app/config/parameters.yml`and `app/config/parameters.yml.dist`files?

Comment: @Matteo Its containing all the credentials. I can't post it :(

Comment: obviously without sensibile data, I suppose that you have same parameters value (or default value in your dist) that are invalid in respect of a bundle configuration, so find a `4`value in your config files and check for relative info about the configuration bundle

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to see a detailed error:

```
$ composer update -vvv
```

I think you have a problem in the configuration of one of your service where you set one more argument than what it is expected (it may happen when you alter the definition of a service in your extension file or in a compiler pass for instance).

This can also be a compatibility problem with one of the bundle. Remember to do the following to have the lastest version of Composer before doing your `composer update`:

```
$ sudo composer self-update
```

Comment: I forget to mention that already run composer self-update and -vvv is not helping. no extra information on error :(

Comment: If you have some services can you give me their configuration (`Resources/config/services.yml`), then the content of your extension file (`DependencyInjection/...Extension.php`) and the compiler passes you have (all files in `DependencyInjection/Compiler/`).

Comment: You can try to display a page to have the detail of the real error (ie. [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\OutOfBoundsException]  
  The index "4" is not in the range [0, 3].)

Comment: You may try to set a real version instead of `dev-master` for all your dependencies in your `composer.json`. This is a possible cause if there was a breaking change in one of these bundles.

Comment: added services.yml and other code files in git. Please have a look. 
I have also tried on page but it doesn't helped much.

Comment: Look at your file `app/logs/dev.log` and search the error `OutOfBoundsException`. Maybe you can have more informations here. If not, try to set the versions of your dependencies as I told you. I cannot see anything that would cause this problem in the code you gave (but you didn't give the code in `DependencyInjection` that would cause that kind of thing).

Comment: DependencyInjection folder added, but I am sure that its not causing any issues.

Comment: Yes no problem here. Replacing `dev-master` is the last thing I can advice you for now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do `redis-cli flushall` before `composer update`?